# How to process source level annotation using Reflection(not using Abstract Processor or APT) in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I can create a processor using Reflection to process the run-time level annotations, but how can i process the source level annotations using reflection?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `AbstractProcessor`?

Answer (score 1):

As the [RetentionPolicy APIdoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) states:

> SOURCE
>
> Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

So the answer is *no*. You either process annotation with `@Retention(SOURCE)` at compile time or they vanish.

If you process them at compile time implementing an `AbstractProcessor` and registring it via *system properties* or configuration of `maven-compiler-plugin` to the compiler is the usual way.